# How to make 3 row in 1 row on tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I want to divide the card into 3 with tailwind css.
how can ı make ?

```
 <Card
      className="grid grid-rows-2"
    >
      <h5 className="font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 row-span-3">{productName}</h5>
      <p className="text-gray-900 text-sm row-span-4">{shortDesc}</p>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-2 row-span-1">
        <span className="font-bold text-gray-900"><Price priceWithTax={priceWithTax} currencyCode={currencyCode} /></span>
      </div>
    </Card>
```

Comment: For reference in Bootstrap you just make 3 divs like this:
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
         first thing
      </div>
   (repeat 2x for other columns)
It seems tailwind is using the grid and grid-rows class instead, but i suspect that -2 is a measurement and if its like bootstrap they add up to 12 .. so you want 3 sets of -4 if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need three equally-sized columns, you can use grid with columns:

```js
<Card className="grid grid-cols-3">
    <h5 className="font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 row-span-3">{productName}</h5>
    <p className="text-gray-900 text-sm row-span-4">{shortDesc}</p>
    <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-2 row-span-1">
        <span className="font-bold text-gray-900"><Price priceWithTax={priceWithTax} currencyCode={currencyCode} /></span>
    </div>
</Card>
```

However, if you want to divide it in three equally-sized rows, you can use grid with rows:

```js
<Card className="grid grid-rows-3">
    <h5 className="font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 row-span-3">{productName}</h5>
    <p className="text-gray-900 text-sm row-span-4">{shortDesc}</p>
    <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-2 row-span-1">
        <span className="font-bold text-gray-900"><Price priceWithTax={priceWithTax} currencyCode={currencyCode} /></span>
    </div>
</Card>
```

The number in `grid-cols-{num}` and `grid-rows-{num}` is the number of columns or rows, as in `grid-template-rows: repeat({num}, minmax(0, 1fr));`. You can see the allowed values [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-rows).

If you need each part to conform to the size of the content, you're better off with flexbox instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a row of 3 Cards by encapsulating a div with class `grid grid-cols-3 gap-4`. `gap-4` will gives some spacing between them.

You can view your corrected code [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/tv9XE2gvZw)

Below is the code also

```
<div className="p-3 grid grid-cols-3 gap-3">
  <Card className="bg-slate-300">
    <h5 className="font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 row-span-3">{productName}</h5>
    <p className="text-gray-900 text-sm row-span-4">{shortDesc}</p>
    <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-2 row-span-1">
      <span className="font-bold text-gray-900"><Price priceWithTax="{priceWithTax}" currencyCode="{currencyCode}" /></span>
    </div>
  </Card>
  <Card className="bg-slate-300">
    <h5 className="font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 row-span-3">{productName}</h5>
    <p className="text-gray-900 text-sm row-span-4">{shortDesc}</p>
    <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-2 row-span-1">
      <span className="font-bold text-gray-900"><Price priceWithTax="{priceWithTax}" currencyCode="{currencyCode}" /></span>
    </div>
  </Card>
  <Card className="bg-slate-300">
    <h5 className="font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 row-span-3">{productName}</h5>
    <p className="text-gray-900 text-sm row-span-4">{shortDesc}</p>
    <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-2 row-span-1">
      <span className="font-bold text-gray-900"><Price priceWithTax="{priceWithTax}" currencyCode="{currencyCode}" /></span>
    </div>
  </Card>
</div>
```

Some resources [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-rows)